# finiteness of homology of augmented Koszul complex

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $(A,m)$ be a local ring $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ elements of $m$ and $M$ a finite $A$-module. Let $K(x)$ be the Koszul complex associated with $x_1,\cdots,x_n$. We define a new complex by $K(x) \otimes M$. Let $H_p(x,M)$ be the homology at dimension $p$ of $K(x) \otimes M$.

> Question: Why is it true that $H_p(x,M)$ is a finite $A$-module?

Remark: This shows up in the proof of the theorem that if $H_1(x,M)=0$ then the sequence $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ is $M$-regular. See for example Lang (Algebra) p. 856, Matsumura (CRT) p. 129.

Comment: Are you assuming that $R$ is Noetherian? If so, then $K(x)$ and $M$ are finitely generated. Hence the submodule corresponding to the kernel is finitely generated. Again by Noetherianness its quotient, $H_p(x,M)$, is finitely generated.

Comment: @Youngsu: Of course, under the Noetherian assumption we get finiteness. But no, i am not assuming Noetherianity and i get the impression that Lang and Matsumura also do not assume that. Maybe there is something else we are missing...

Comment: Posted and solved (by a counterexample) on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145773/finiteness-of-the-homology-of-an-augmented-koszul-complex

Comment: Crossposting is frowned upon, but if you are going to crosspost, at least provide a link in each to the other.